# Is there a way to set static homescreen wallpaper programmaticaly?

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-wallpaper

I'm modifying an android launcher. And I want to set the first screen to be a static image, while all other screens will be other static images. How can I do that from the home screen code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developers you can.

It's part of their [demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/SetWallpaperActivity.html) suite.